# Modeling an exponential decay

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I am given the following problem:

> The burial cloth of an Egyptian mummy is estimated to contain 59% of the carbon-14 it contained originally. How long ago was the mummy buried?

Is it wrong to calculate it as it follows? $$0.59=1 \cdot (1-0.5)^x$$

From that, I got 4361 years, but a colleague has 4396 as an answer. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Thank you.

**Edit:** I used 5730 as C-14's half life.

Comment: Here's a similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3337801/modelling-exponential-decay-of-a-radioactive-substance/3337807#3337807

Comment: Please note that surely, the fact that it's **carbon-14** has something to do with the solution.

Comment: What value of half-life were you given? I googled and got 5730 years, and using that, your answer of 4361 years is much closer.

Comment: I also think that you didn't really show us all the equations. How did you go from
$$
0.59 = 0.5^x
$$
to the answer $4361$?

Comment: @MattiP. sorry I forgot to mention, I used 5730 as C-14's half-life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same answer. I assume that after $5730$ years  50% of the original $14C$ content will be left.

To determine the decay (d) per year I used the equation $d^{5730}=0.5\Rightarrow d=0.5^{\frac1{5730}}$

Therefore the equation is

$$\left(0.5^{\frac1{5730}} \right)^x=0.59$$

$$x\cdot \log\left(0.5^{\frac1{5730}}\right)=\log(0.59)\Rightarrow x=\frac{\log(0.59)}{\log\left(0.5^{\frac1{5730}}\right)}\approx 4361.7$$

**Remark**

We can use the following equation to find out which half-life your colleague has used: $$\frac{\log(0.59)}{\log(0.5^{1/x})}=4396\Rightarrow x\approx 5775$$

Answer (score 1):

The half life of Carbon 14 is $5730$ years so the correct calculation is to first solve

$$0.59=0.5^x$$

which gives $x\approx 0.7612$ and then calculate $0.7612$ half lives i.e. $4361$ years.